# Trouble posting data to website with axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

How can I send this data that I'm getting to an other website? I need to use `axios` and express, that's why it's with `axios` and not request. I tried some stuff but it keeps saying undefined.

```
async function rainbowAPI(error, Results, body) {
  await axios
    //Get data van json file pc only
    .get(`${baseUrl}search=${username}`, {})
    .then(Response => {
      //PlayerId en playerName weergeven in console 
      //Er is ook nog p_user wat niet altijd matcht met p_id
      //p_user kan gebruikt worden om de player avatar te krijgen
      console.log(`PlayerId   ${Response.data.results[0].p_id}`)
      console.log(`UserName   ${Response.data.results[0].p_name}`)
      //Als de naam die ingegeven werd geen bestaande user is.
      if (Response.data.results[0].p_id === undefined) {
        //Status 400 versturen
      }
      //Als het een bestaande user is, verstuur je de data
      else {
        return Response;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //Foutafhandeling
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to check that result is array or not
and you have to p_id exists or not in that result object then you can proceed to send that data to another request

```
  await axios
            //Get data van json file pc only
            .get(`${baseUrl}search=${username}`, {   
            })
            .then(async (Response) => {
                    //PlayerId en playerName weergeven in console 
                    //Er is ook nog p_user wat niet altijd matcht met p_id
                    //p_user kan gebruikt worden om de player avatar te krijgen

                    // first check results object 
                    if(Response.data.hasOwnProperty("results") && len(Response.data.results) ){
                             if(Response.data.results[0].hasOwnProperty("p_id")){
                             // now p_id exists 
                              console.log(`PlayerId   ${Response.data.results[0].p_id}`)
                    console.log(`UserName   ${Response.data.results[0].p_name}`) 
                    //Als de naam die ingegeven werd geen bestaande user is.
                    if(Response.data.results[0].p_id === undefined){
                        //Status 400 versturen
                    }
                //Als het een bestaande user is, verstuur je de data
                    else{
                        return Response;
                    }
}
                     }
              })
            .catch((err) => {
                //Foutafhandeling
                console.error(err);
            });
}
```